# the model of type could not be updated mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i am trying to update model with some changes like below

```
inventory.SiteId=Siteitem.Siteid;
inventory.CreatedBy=currentuser;
inventory.CreatedDate=DateTime.Today;

TryUpdateModel(inventory);
```

or

```
UpdateModel(inventory);
```

both are failed to update the model

Answer (score 22):

So the question is "Why is it failing?"  One thing you could look at is the ModelState dictionary and see if the model is is valid and if there are errors.  There's a reason it's failing, of course.  I think that would be one of my first checks.  Maybe you've got a mismatch of some sort - integer on one side and string on the other, for instance.

Comment: Good approach and advice. This led me directly to the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Glad that helped, Dan.  Make it a great day.

Comment: This is the second time in a month that I've googled for "model of type could not be upated" and come to this answer.  Maybe the exception should say something like, "See ModelState for details."

Comment: Yes, agree modelState should be valid . good catch ! solved issue

Answer (score 1):

Remember here that TryUpdateModel updates the model with values from your form. Are you trying to update the model in your database? If so you need to specify this. If you set inventory.Whatever above, your model is already set with those values.

The only time to call TryUpdateModel is when you want to take those form values and put them into the model and set ModelState (which will then contain any errors as part of this process as well)